# Can't print documents or almost anything

Tags: windows-10, hp-spectre

EDIT: Right clicking on the the pdf/text document prints it but I need the menu before that to select how it prints. This menu can be brought up only on the printer properties, but on all other computers it shows it prior to printing each document. Screenshot - https://take.ms/RSi3o

Laptop used - HP Spectre x360 13"

Printer currently installed and working on the Network - Xerox Phaser 3260

Drivers are installed, laptop restarted. It prints the test page.

While on a pdf file for example(or word/txt/etc) shortcut ctrl + P does nothing.

Print button is greyed out, as seen on the screenshot.

Opening the pdf through web browser, the print button is not greyed out but clicking it does nothing.

Note that when trying to print a web page, it opens it and it works just fine. [image]

Comment: This seems more of an issue with your software. What app is this? You can also force the printer to be the default printer in settings. It may help.

Comment: Printer is set as default.

Comment: See if your Printer driver was set up for a WSD port, and if so try using a straight TCP/IP Port

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears that the several documents I needed printed were locked for printing.

Still not option to print a text file. No idea why but I don't need it anyway.